# SQL Server : splitting weighted values into groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, weighted

I have an issue that I hoped would have an easy solution, however, been hitting my head off a brick wall. I have a table which contains:

- ItemID
- ItemValue
- Group

What I had hoped was to split all the items into groups where the sum of the ItemValues in a group was roughly equal. So far my efforts with ntile etc have produced very uneven groups. This is using SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.6220).

Any help very much appreciated.

Code for creating table:

```
------------------------------
--Table structure for [TstGroupWeight]
------------------------------
DROP TABLE [TstGroupWeight]
GO
CREATE TABLE [TstGroupWeight] 
(
    [ItemID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    [ItemValue] int NULL ,
    [Group] int NULL 
)
GO

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of TstGroupWeight
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'1', N'36', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'2', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'3', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'4', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'5', N'1', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'6', N'16', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'7', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'8', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'9', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'10', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'11', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'12', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'13', N'36', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'14', N'36', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'15', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'16', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'17', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'18', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'19', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'20', N'10', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'21', N'6', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'22', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'23', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'24', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'25', N'15', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'26', N'29', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'27', N'42', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'28', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'29', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'30', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'31', N'33', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'32', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'33', N'40', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'34', N'29', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'35', N'15', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'36', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'37', N'28', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'38', N'19', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'39', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'40', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'41', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'42', N'22', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'43', N'7', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'44', N'8', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'45', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'46', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'47', N'19', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'48', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'49', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'50', N'32', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'51', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'52', N'28', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'53', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'54', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'55', N'33', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'56', N'40', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'57', N'19', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'58', N'42', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'59', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'60', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'61', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'62', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'63', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'64', N'36', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'65', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'66', N'15', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'67', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'68', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'69', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'70', N'7', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'71', N'1', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'72', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'73', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'74', N'22', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'75', N'20', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'76', N'1', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'77', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'78', N'39', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'79', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'80', N'33', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'81', N'0', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'82', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'83', N'24', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'84', N'36', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'85', N'29', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'86', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'87', N'6', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'88', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'89', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'90', N'19', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'91', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'92', N'25', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'93', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'94', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'95', N'28', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'96', N'16', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'97', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'98', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'99', N'25', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'100', N'14', null);
GO
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'101', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'102', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'103', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'104', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'105', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'106', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'107', N'0', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'108', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'109', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'110', N'39', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'111', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'112', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'113', N'25', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'114', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'115', N'3', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'116', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'117', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'118', N'3', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'119', N'15', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'120', N'0', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'121', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'122', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'123', N'6', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'124', N'6', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'125', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'126', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'127', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'128', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'129', N'31', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'130', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'131', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'132', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'133', N'40', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'134', N'30', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'135', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'136', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'137', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'138', N'31', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'139', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'140', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'141', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'142', N'10', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'143', N'36', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'144', N'32', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'145', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'146', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'147', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'148', N'17', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'149', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'150', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'151', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'152', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'153', N'23', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'154', N'28', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'155', N'32', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'156', N'25', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'157', N'17', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'158', N'1', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'159', N'42', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'160', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'161', N'29', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'162', N'23', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'163', N'6', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'164', N'32', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'165', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'166', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'167', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'168', N'29', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'169', N'16', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'170', N'20', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'171', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'172', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'173', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'174', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'175', N'22', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'176', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'177', N'0', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'178', N'30', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'179', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'180', N'30', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'181', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'182', N'31', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'183', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'184', N'42', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'185', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'186', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'187', N'29', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'188', N'7', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'189', N'5', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'190', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'191', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'192', N'16', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'193', N'29', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'194', N'16', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'195', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'196', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'197', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'198', N'0', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'199', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'200', N'20', null);
GO
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'201', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'202', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'203', N'6', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'204', N'42', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'205', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'206', N'31', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'207', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'208', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'209', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'210', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'211', N'28', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'212', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'213', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'214', N'7', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'215', N'40', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'216', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'217', N'7', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'218', N'15', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'219', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'220', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'221', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'222', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'223', N'41', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'224', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'225', N'23', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'226', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'227', N'39', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'228', N'28', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'229', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'230', N'8', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'231', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'232', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'233', N'23', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'234', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'235', N'40', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'236', N'0', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'237', N'24', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'238', N'24', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'239', N'22', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'240', N'20', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'241', N'39', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'242', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'243', N'42', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'244', N'7', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'245', N'27', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'246', N'8', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'247', N'7', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'248', N'19', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'249', N'21', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'250', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'251', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'252', N'30', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'253', N'19', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'254', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'255', N'14', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'256', N'28', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'257', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'258', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'259', N'10', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'260', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'261', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'262', N'0', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'263', N'39', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'264', N'35', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'265', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'266', N'6', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'267', N'2', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'268', N'24', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'269', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'270', N'10', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'271', N'13', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'272', N'16', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'273', N'16', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'274', N'3', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'275', N'3', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'276', N'26', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'277', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'278', N'23', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'279', N'4', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'280', N'34', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'281', N'23', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'282', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'283', N'17', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'284', N'25', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'285', N'32', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'286', N'24', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'287', N'37', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'288', N'38', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'289', N'18', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'290', N'40', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'291', N'12', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'292', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'293', N'9', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'294', N'32', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'295', N'11', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'296', N'23', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'297', N'25', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'298', N'30', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'299', N'24', null);
INSERT INTO [TstGroupWeight] VALUES (N'300', N'6', null);
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889830/create-evenly-sized-groups-based-on-aggregate

Answer (score 0):

This is a bin-packing problem and the general solution is probably too difficult for SQL.  One method that works pretty well in practice is to enumerate the groups and then take even nth value for each group.  So, if you wanted three groups:

```
select t.*, (seqnum % 3) as grp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by itemvalue) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

This works when the values are within a smallish rather dense range (as well as under other circumstances).  It does not work when there are a small number of outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create those groups based on data sorted by `ItemID` your `NTILE` fails because it creates groups with the same number of rows but not the same sum. You just need to apply the quantile logic based on the *cumulative sum* of values.

Calculating **n** quantiles is very similar to:

```
n * (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ItemID) - 1) 
    / COUNT(*) OVER()
```

Now change the counts to `SUM`:

```
(n  * sum(ItemValue) over (order by ItemID rows unbounded preceding) - 1) 
    / sum(ItemValue) over ()
```

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support Cumulative Sums, so you need to use a Correlated Subquery (performance might be bad).

```
with cte as
 (
   select ItemID, ItemValue,

    -- sum of all values 
      sum(ItemValue) over () as all_sum,

    -- cumulative sum
      (select sum(ItemValue) 
       from TstGroupWeight as t2
       where t2.ItemID <= t1.ItemID) as cum_sum

    -- much easier in SQL Server 2012 
    --   sum(ItemValue) 
    --   over (order by ItemID
    --         rows unbounded preceding) as cum_sum
   from TstGroupWeight as t1
 )
select ItemID, ItemValue, cum_sum,
  -- n = number of quantiles
   (n * cum_sum-1) / all_sum as grp
from cte
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc2be/3)

Of course the same logic can be applied using recursion (or a cursor), but depending on the actual number of rows all versions might run slow.